# sudo command fails in ubuntu 17.10 with keyError

Tags: sudo, 17.10, wayland

I upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10.
Now when I run

```
sudo gedit
```

I get the error

```
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyError: Can't open display: :0
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Other root applications are broken on Wayland too (see [bug 1713313](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1713313) and [bug 1713311](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1713311)
).

Answer (score 1):

Run:

```
xhost local:user1
```

(Replace `user1` with your username.)

Comment: sudo=root not user: `xhost local:root`. and this command may not work on waylnd which is default for 17.10

Comment: in my case I use "xhost local:tom" and it works.

Comment: then your .Xauthority has `xhost local:root` in it. you should correct your answer so that is applies to more users.

Comment: I think it is a poor quality answer as it throws out a command without explanation or information on how to reverse the command

Comment: xhost +local: does it